# How to select element in jQuery by ID when ID is a variable?

Tags: jquery, selector

I have a variable`gamma = neww;`

where neww is ID of an element.

Now how do I select this element using jQuery?

```
$(#gamma).code
```

does not work.

What I want to do is remove Class of this element using `removeClass()` which is a jQuery function.

Comment: Search before you post. `$("#" + gamma).removeClass()` may help.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$('#'+gamma).code`
or `$('#'+gamma).removeClass()`

Comment: oh yeah!..didn't think that :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the selector as a string:

```
$("#"+gamma)
```